# What is the point of casting long to integer?

Tags: java

```
public class ConstantsAndCasting{
     public static void main (String args[]){
          long hugeNum = 23456013477456L;
          int smallNum = (int)hugeNum;
          System.out.println(hugeNum);
          System.out.println(smallNum); 
     }
}
```

The output to the code listed above is:

```
23456013477456 
1197074000
```

It appears as though when casting a long to an integer value, java retains 32 bits starting from the right working left. What results is a value that is closer to 0 than to the original long value. This totally makes sense from a machine perspective but what is the practical use for this? It seems like you'd be better off using the random number generator to produce 10 random characters.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `long` may contain values that fit in `int`, so if you happened to store some value within `long` that is small enough to fit in `int` and you have to pass the number as an int, that would be the purpose I guess.

Comment: If you need an `int` but you have a `long` then you are forced to cast the value. I don't get your question, the point of a cast is to make a type be seen as another type, it's not done unless you have this requirement. The result of casting a `long` value outside the bounds of an `int` to an `int` is another matter.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little unclear how to answer that...  As with any type conversion, it iis used when you have a value of one type (in this case, long) but you need a value of a different type (in this case, int).

Yes, sometimes it will give you unwanted results, because of the limitations of the casting operation (Which, in turn, are based on the limitations of the data types).  But picking one of those out, and saying "so what's the point in ever doing this operation", would be like saying "if I have two ints, `a` and `b`, each valued at 2,000,000,000 - adding them doesn't get the desired result... so what's the point adding ints?"

Answer (score 0):

The primary useful purpose of casting a `long` to an `int` is to take a `long` value which is in the range -2147483648..2147483647 and use that number with code that expects an `int` value in that range.  The behavior with values was outside that range was chosen because:

1. The designers of Java wanted to fully specify its behavior whenever practical.
2. Taking the bottom 32 bits and ignoring the top 32 bits was faster than any other *consistent* course of action which would work sensibly with values in the range -2147483648..2147483647.

There are a number of situations where other courses of action might sometimes allow more efficient code generation if consistency wasn't required, or more useful semantics if speed wasn't required.  The approach that was taken, however, offers the best compromise between speed, usefulness, and consistency.